# D11 Test mid build

Tags: technic, control-plus

On step 198 of D11 Technic set the instruction asks you to test the gears. When I test it, the gear switches but never runs the test to spin the right gear. It does that on each gear it tests.

[image: Step 198]

I tried to check if the gears work by advancing to calibration, although the set is not finished. It correctly picks the gears to calibrate the "shovel". I am lost. It looks like an app issue.

Comment: I have the same problem with my D11, have you figured it out? Itchy head now